# Finatra: How can I inject a property value to the controller?

Tags: scala, finatra

I want to do something like that

```
class AssetsController @Inject()(path: String) extends Controller {
  // ...
}
```

The path should be taken from `application.conf` where the key is `path.to.something`. In the future, I may add some other properties (source is the same `*.conf` file) to my controller.

Is it possible to that in `Finatra`?

PS

When using `Spring Framework` you can inject a value in this way

```
@Value("#{configuration.key}")
private String key;
```

Maybe in `Finatra` there is something similar to String approach?

Answer (score 0):

Finatra doesn't read configuration from files. You have to pass the config via command line options and can get the options via `@Flag` annotation. For example,

```
$ java -jar app.jar -path=/foo/bar

// MyController.scala
class MyController @Inject(@Flag("path") path: String) {
  def index(request: Request) = {
    path // "/foo/bar"
  }
}
```

You can read the [doc](http://twitter.github.io/finatra/user-guide/getting-started/#flags) for more info.